# company policy vs. company's policy

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference between company policy and company's policy in meaning or are they the same in practice?

Gold market, oil market and bond market all sounds perfectly normal, but why do English speakers choose to say financial market, not finance market?

Use of modifer sometimes seems inconsistent and therefore confusing to non-English speakers.

Comment: Yes, it can be confusing. A rule of thumb (though far from universally holding) is that an adjective is preferred if there is one (eg 'financial'), then an attributive noun (eg 'company' policy, a 'car' tyre) where association rather than true ownership / possession (their 'company's' policy; Jean's 'car's' rear nearside tyre) is in play. Sometimes, one form may have a different meaning from that of another.

Comment: "*noun* policy" can refer to policy on a particular thing, e.g. sickness policy, recruitment policy mean policy regarding (employee) sickness or recruitment; "*noun's* policy" means policy belonging to whatever noun is. *Company policy* could also refer to something like an insurance policy for a company (rather than for an individual): "Rather than pay individual travel insurance for every worker, we need a company policy."

Comment: Edwin Ashworth & Stuart F///I really appreciate your tips. They are really helpful.